# Magic submit button!

Tags: css

The following code seems to be valid:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> <html> <head>
<title>Sample Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
  input {width:500px; padding:3px; background:green; border:1px solid red;}
  textarea {width:500px; height:150px; padding:3px; background:green ; border:1px solid red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="">
    <p><input id="entry_0"><label for="entry_0">Name</label></p>
    <p><input id="entry_1"><label for="entry_1">Email</label></p>
    <p><input id="entry_2"><label for="entry_2">URL</label></p>
    <p><textarea id="entry_3" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the submit button width is shorter than other fields. Strangely when I remove the doctype declaration, they all get the same length. What am I doing wrong and how can I make them the same size?

Thanks in advance! 
Rain Lover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
webkit-box-sizing: content-box ; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: content-box ;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: content-box ;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

to your `input` css rule, to be sure.

**Note**: It is a CSS3 property, so it is not applicable to non-modern browsers.
**Reference**: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing

Answer (score 1):

```
input {display:block; width:500px; padding:3px; background:green; border:1px solid red;}
```

This should work. Adding `Display:Block;` will make your width and height attributes work properly.

Comment: It gave it a try, bu it made no difference.